# Lista de listas a CSV en Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, lista, csv

A traves del CSV que dejo al final del codigo obtengo la informacion que va a ser modificada con mi codigo. El problema es que cuando ya tengo la informacion que quiero y busco guardarla en un CSV nuevo no puedo ya que solo me copia la primer fila del CSV y no todas

Codigo:

```
import csv
with open('report_2017_12_06_23_06_16UTC.csv') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
    for row in reader:
        row['fillRate'] = float(row['fillRate'])
        row['fillRate'] = row['fillRate']*100
        row['fillRate'] = '%.2f' % row['fillRate']
        row['fillRate'] = str(row['fillRate'])
        if row['domain'] == row['ddomain']:
            row['domain'] = row['ddomain']
        else: 
            row['domain'] =  row['ddomain']+" (MD != MR)"
        a = (row['trafficChannel'], row['date'], row['domain'], row['country'], row['opportunities'], row['impressions'], row['fillRate'])

        your_list = list(a)

        your_list = ', '.join(your_list)

with open("file.csv", "w") as output:
    for items in your_list:
        output.write(str(items))
```

[CSV](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Y9kd806vT5PK4OiLN8_DaE7WC7UWMwMd/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Martin el csv que se supone que debe contener, dos filas siendo la primera `aaa,bbb,ccc` y la segunda `ddd,fff,ggg` para tu ejemplo? ¿Y que son  `aaa`,  `bbb`,  `ccc` etc? porque la lista que muestras no es una lista Python válida como tal. ¿son cadenas o referencias a otros objetos?

Comment: Asímismo, Martin, corrige el código para que sea un [ejemplo mínimo y **verificable**](/help/mcve).

Comment: yo tengo un `csv` y lo converti a una lista con el nombre de la variable `your_list`. El `csv` es de 7 columnas x 10000 filas. y lo que quiero hacer es guardar esa data que hay en `your_list` en un nuevo `csv`

Comment: Edite la pregunta con todo el codigo

Comment: te recomiendo leer y escribir los ficheros usando el modulo csv: https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/csv.html

Comment: lo segui de pie a cabeza pero no encuentro como hacer lo que necesito

Comment: ¿Martin seria posible que agregaras unas cuantas filas del principio del csv original a la pregunta para facilitar la reproducción del código?  Ahora mismo tu lista final solo contiene la última fila del csv.Si entiendo lo que pretendes (modificar ciertas columnas del csv y guardar los cambios en otro archivo) no necesitas una lista para nada, usa csv.DictWriter y ve escribiendo las filas según las modificas.

Comment: CSV Añadido a la descripcion de la pregunta!

Answer (score 1):

El primer problema es que al hacer `your_list = list(a)` en cada fila del csv, al final a solo contiene la última fila. Para que tu aproximación fuera correcta deberias añadir a la lista (list.append) cada fila modificada dentro del `for` y al final iterar sobre ella escribiendo cada sublista como una fila.

No obstante, en vez de crear una lista que es poco eficiente (terminas con todo el csv en memoria y es lenta de construir), deberías usar `csv.DictWriter` para ir escribiendo directamente cada fila según vas iterando sobre el archivo original.

Tu código puede quedar algo así:

```
import csv

input_file = 'report_2017_12_06_23_06_16UTC.csv'
output_file= "file.csv"

with open(input_file) as csvfile, open(output_file,  "w") as output:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
    writer = csv.DictWriter(output, fieldnames=reader.fieldnames)
    writer.writeheader()
    for row in reader:
        row['fillRate'] = '{:.2f}'.format(float(row['fillRate']) * 100)
        row['domain'] = row['ddomain'] if row['domain'] == row['ddomain']\
                                           else row['ddomain'] + " (MD != MR)"
        writer.writerow(row)
```

---

**Edición:**

Si no quieres todas las columnas simplemente pásale un iterable con las que quieres al parámetro `fielnames` de [`csv.DictWriter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.DictWriter) y especifica el parámetro `extrasaction` como `"ignore"`:

```
import csv

input_file = 'report_2017_12_06_23_06_16UTC.csv'
output_file= "file.csv"

with open(input_file) as csvfile, open(output_file,  "w") as output:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
    cols = ("trafficChannel", "date", "domain", "country",
            "opportunities", "impressions", "fillRate")
    writer = csv.DictWriter(output, fieldnames=cols, extrasaction='ignore')

    writer.writeheader()
    for row in reader:
        row['fillRate'] = '{:.2f}'.format(float(row['fillRate']) * 100)
        row['domain'] = row['ddomain'] if row['domain'] == row['ddomain']\
                                           else row['ddomain'] + " (MD != MR)"
        writer.writerow(row)
```

Que para el csv de ejemplo que muestras:

```
trafficChannel,trafficChannelId,date,domain,ddomain,country,opportunities,impressions,fillRate
aaaa,,11/29/17,juegos.com,juegos.com,ES,994,8,0.00804829
aaaa,,11/29/17,vinted.cz,vinted.cz,CZ,203,1,0.004926108
aaaa,,11/29/17,collinsdictionary.com,collinsdictionary.com,BE,421,1,0.002375297
aaaa,,11/30/17,urldelivery.com,chatytvgratishd.me,CO,490,1,0.002040816
aaaa,,11/30/17,androidpit.com.br,androidpit.com.br,BR,125,2,0.016
aaaa,,12/1/17,eredmenyek.com,eredmenyek.com,HU,230,1,0.004347826
```

Obtenemos:

```
trafficChannel,date,domain,country,opportunities,impressions,fillRate
aaaa,11/29/17,juegos.com,ES,994,8,0.80
aaaa,11/29/17,vinted.cz,CZ,203,1,0.49
aaaa,11/29/17,collinsdictionary.com,BE,421,1,0.24
aaaa,11/30/17,chatytvgratishd.me (MD != MR),CO,490,1,0.20
aaaa,11/30/17,androidpit.com.br,BR,125,2,1.60
aaaa,12/1/17,eredmenyek.com,HU,230,1,0.43
```

Comment: Eso es lo que buscaba, lo unico que me falta agregar es que quiero que solo me muestre algunas columnas, necesito que no me grabe en el nuevo csv las columnas de `trafficChannelId` ni `ddomain`

Comment: Simplemente pasa a `fielnames` del `writer` solo las columnas que quieras. Espera un momento, voy a editar.

Comment: Okey, gracias!!

Comment: @MartinBouhier al final de la respuesta he añadido como hacer lo que comentas. cualquier problema comenta. Un saludo.

Comment: Perfecto, lo unico que me quedaria es saber como puedo agregarle una columna al csv original que se llame "Data" y este al final de todas las columnas, dsp de "fillrate"

Comment: ¿Querrías añadirla a `report_2017_12_06_23_06_16UTC.csv` pero no a `file.csv`? Tienes dos opciones, o cargar el csv en memoria al completo, añadir la columna y luego sobreescribir el archivo o bien hacer como se hace aquí, crear un 3º csv en disco e ir añadiendo las filas con la nueva columna y al final de todo sobreescribir un fichero con el otro.

Comment: Se la quiero añadir a `report_2017_12_06_23_06_16UTC.csv`, no se como realizar los pasos que dices...

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/69863/discussion-between-fjsevilla-and-martin-bouhier).